# SSRS Sparkline category with Lookup

Tags: reporting-services, sparklines

I have a table in which I have to use SSRS Sparklines. But the requirement is that, I have to lookup the Y axis values and Category groups from another dataset, using a unique identifier in both the datasets. Lets say DS1 is the parent dataset and DS2 has got the Y values and Category (12 months) for the Sparkline.

I cannot use DS2 as Default dataset for the table, because it will result in writing lookup expressions for around 20-25 cells other than Sparkline cell.

So I used the below expressions for Sparkline.

Value axis :

```
=lookupset(Fields!RowID.Value,Fields!RowID.Value,Fields!Trend.Value,"DS2")
```

Category axis :

```
=lookupset(Fields!RowID.Value,Fields!RowID.Value,Fields!MonthName.Value,"DS2")
```

I used lookup set, because I believe we have to map a set of values to the Sparkline chart.  But it throws me the below error.

[image]

Any suggestions to solve the error? Is it possible to configure a Sparkline without Category axis? I asked because I can manage my chart if SParkline can plot the trend values alone, without a category axis also.

Comment: Share the datasets structure and the desired output in order to help you

Comment: Thanks for that, Alejandro Zuleta.. I use an MDX Dataset. Sorry I am not able to share the complete dataset, but the structure of DS1 is that, it has got a RowID. DS2 has got RowID and all the months in rows, along with the Sales values of each month in corresponding rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join Keyword to avoid the "datatype that is not valid" error.

=Join(lookupset(Fields!RowID.Value,Fields!RowID.Value, Fields!MonthName.Value,"DS2"),"," + vbcrlf)

But the problem now is, All the Month names are displaying at one point in x-axis(Category axis).

Appreciate any help to get the Month names individually rather than at 1 point on category axis?